# PhP Namespaces in input types

Tags: php, zend-framework, io, namespaces

I have the following oddity in our development enviroment. Lets say i have 2 classes 
one is in namespace \wtf

```
namespace \wtf\isWrongHere;

class DrStrange {

}
```

And i have an other class wich i am passing the class via dependency injection

```
 namespace \normalPpl;


     class ThisHasNoLogic {
       public function __construct(DrStrange $strange){ 
           //here be dragons
       }
     }
```

Now when i instanziate the class via:

```
$whata = new ThisHasNoLogic(new \wtf\isWrongHere\DrStrange());
```

On My dev debian machine i get normal instance, on our dev machine(a clone of our live server) i get normall results to.

**BUT on our live machine i get a fatal error. How is that possible?**

**`PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to xxxx must be an instance of xxxxx, instance of aaaaar given, called in ....QQ`**

In all servers it is acepting the input type but on live it dous tel me tht the class passed dous not match the required...

aka \wtf\isWrongHere\DrStrange ist not a instance of DrStrange, wich is just plain WTH@12 moment for me.

Here are the specs:

development Machine:

> PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug  6 2012
>   14:18:06) Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0,
>   Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
>       with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Server built:   Apr  1 2012 07:14:38
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Test machine:

```
PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Mar  4 2013 13:11:17)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH

Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Server built:   Mar  3 2013 12:09:44
```

Live:

```
PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Mar  4 2013 13:11:17)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH



Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Server built:   Mar  3 2013 12:09:44
```

I dont know what to do to make the test server behave like the Live. Anyone any sugesstions??

UPDATE:

When i use  the:

use \wtf\isWrongHere\DrStrange;

It works. But i have no way to reproduce it on the test systems which are ignoring this error. i want to replicate it on a diferent machine. Tht is my actual problem which is pleguing my team for over 1 year.

Comment: Tht is pseudo code. Will corect it. (update: done it :D)

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the DrStrange namespace to have it work.

```
namespace \normalPpl;

use wtf\isWrongHere\DrStrange;

 class ThisHasNoLogic {
   public function __constructor(DrStrange $strange){ 
       //here be dragons
   }
 }
```

Given you have a good autoload (see [psr-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) or [php spl_autoload](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.spl-autoload.php) )

Comment: Aaa forgot to tell it. Already did tht, and that fixes the problem. The actual problem is tht i have no way to test my code and want to replicate it on my test machine (will update question)

Comment: This problem, not being able to test is always geting to us wihch causes untestable errors to occure, and gives us a hell of a scare every 2 months.

Comment: Did you gave a look to my last sentence and investigated the autoloading solution. This is a best-practice.

Comment: Yes i did. As told, we know the solution to use the namespace, the problem is that the same code works on our dev and test server but not on our live server. Something is setup diferently in PHP i am suspecting, but dont know what.

Comment: Did you tried [Composer autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)?